# How to upload a PDF Document on Cloudinary

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, cloudinary

I am trying to upload a PDF document on Cloudinary through a node.js server.
The current approach I am using is inadequate and doesn't work.
I will appreciate if anyone can proffer a solution to this problem that works, thank you.

Cloudinary Storage Configuration:

```
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2,
  { CloudinaryStorage } = require("multer-storage-cloudinary");  

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});
 
const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary: cloudinary,
  folder: "<some_folder>",
  allowedFormats: ["jpg", "png", "pdf"],
});


module.exports.store = storage;
```

Image Upload Route:

```
const express = require("express"),
  router = express.Router(),
  cors = require("cors"),
  fileUploadController = require("../../../controllers/haulage/users/fileUploadController");

const authenticate = require("../../../auth/auth"),
  multer = require("multer"),
  storage = require("../../../../config/cloudinary").store,
  parser = multer({ storage: storage });

router
  .route("/images")
  .put(
    authenticate,
    cors(),
    parser.array("image"),
    fileUploadController.uploadImage
  );

module.exports = router;
```

Image Upload Controller:

```
exports.uploadImage = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const events = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.files));

    const urls = [];    

    events.map((e) => {
      const url = e.path;
     
      urls.push(url);
    });

    res.status(201).json({ URLS: urls });
  } catch {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Server Error, Image Failed to Add" });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you part of the free plan in Cloudinary? If yes, it might be related to this issue: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016480179-Why-does-my-pdf-link-isn-t-working-
If not, can you please elaborate on the issue? where do you see the error?
The code to upload pdf ( same as any image):

```
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary')
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload("https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf",function(res,err){console.log(res,err)});
```

Comment: Yes, I am using a free plan, but that's not where the issue lies. The issue with using the method you suggested is that I don't know how to represent the pdf file sent to the server as a string, which is the first argument of the upload method. In this scenario, the file is sent as formdata.

Comment: I have no issues uploading images, though I use a different approach to achieve that. I make use of multer which is linked to my cloudinary storage. The problem is that it saves pdf files as images, that's why I am seeking a different approach. Please find the method I use in uploading images in the question section.

Comment: you can open a ticket to support@cloudinary.com and we can look at our logs.

Comment: I later sent an email to cloudinary and found out that the issue was what was stated in the link you sent. I gave them the details they asked for and the restriction was lifted from the account. Thanks for posting that link, I had no idea an issue like that existed prior to this.

Comment: If anyone runs into this, you can now remove this restriction yourself directly from the Settings -> Security tab in Cloudinary. The above link that @ShirlyManor shared has since been updated and also has the instructions.